# AngularJs mutliple layouts for different routes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to setup a complex AngularJS based application with multiple templates and layouts. But i don't really understand the routing mechanism of angularjs, so i am looking for further explanation about it and maybe some examples if possible.

I have many layouts that I would like to use with different templates based on routes.

---

### Error Pages:

It's a simple error page with different messages to the user.

**Layout:**

```
layouts/error.html
```

**Templates:**

```
templates/error/404.html
templates/error/505.html
templates/error/403.html
```

These pages

### Internal Pages:

To visit these pages it is required for the users to sign in.

**Layout:**

```
layouts/internal.html
```

This layout has a sidebar on the left side that has a menu and a chat box that diplays messages from other logged in users, and i would like to avoid it to be reloaded when the user is navigating.

**Template Routes:**

```
/dashboard -> templates/internal/dashboard.html
/profile -> templates/internal/profile.html
/settings -> templates/internal/settings.html
/library -> templates/internal/library.html
etc..
```

### Public Pages:

Public pages that are available for anyone.

**Layout:**

```
layouts/public.html
```

**Templates:**

```
registration -> templates/public/registration.html
sign in -> templates/public/signin.html
forgot password -> templates/public/forgotpassword.html
about us -> templates/public/aboutus.html
etc..
```

How should i set up the routing for this in angularjs?

Comment: https://scotch.io/tutorials/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating#configure-routes-and-views

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an empty main-Layout (eg index.html) which contains nothing but a ng-view container in the body. The view can be changed depending on the route.

Example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="phonecatApp">
<head>
...
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then you can include different partials in the ng-view depending on the route. For more details and example code, see this tutorial: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

If you want to build more complex layouts with nested views/templates, take a look at ui-router:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Comment: I am using ui-router i forgot to mention that in my question. Can you please give me an example using ui-router? I can't figure out how to setup nested layouts.

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router#nested-states--views  You just have one ui-view in your main template in the body, but you also add ui-views in your templates. You can combine this with named states, if you want, too! (ui-view="viewName") to include multiple templates in one page!